# JAVA, GUI JPanel, JFrame, paintComponent, Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

Regarding your comment to change add public display(Graphics g)

[link]http://www3.canyons.edu/Faculty/biblej/project6.html

1.)Project6 class will have to extend the JFrame class
2.)Project6 constructor will have to set up the GUI window.
3.)A new abstract method:  public void display(Graphics g);  should be added to the base and derived classes
4.)A custom JPanel must be set up with a paintComponent method
5.)The new display(Graphics g) method will have to draw the shapes on the GUI window and be called from a loop in the paintComponent method

```
public class Project6 extends JFrame { 

//project6 constructor without parameters to set up new JFrame
public Project6() {
add(new NewPanel());
}
class NewPanel extends JPanel {
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);
```

//So do I need to add Graphics g here? or no?

```
for(int i = 0; i < thearray.length && thearray[i] != null; i++) {
thearray[i].display(**Graphics g**); 
}}}

public static void main (String [] args) {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(800, 700);                           
frame.setTitle("Shapes");
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                 //Center Frame
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Here is one of classes for example, Do I add it to the end like this? and do I need to add a public abstract void display(Graphics g) to the Shape parent class? and how would it call in the project6 class?

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {
private int width;
private int height;

public Rectangle() {
    setWidth(0);
    setHeight(0);
    setXPos(0);
    setYPos(0);}

public Rectangle(int xPos, int yPos, int height, int width) {
    setWidth(xPos);
    setHeight(yPos);
    setXPos(height);
    setYPos(width);}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;}

public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;}

@Override
public void display() {
    System.out.println("Rectangle: (" + getXPos() + ", " + getYPos() + ") " + " Height:  " + height + " Width: " + width);}

@Override
public void display(Graphics g) {
  g.drawRect(getXPos(), getYPos(), width, height); }
```

Comment: When I mean by adding the Graphics g i mean adding it into thearray[i].display(GRAPHICS G), and I also need the display() to read but Im not sure how to put both together because it just says it cant find the graphics g symbol

Answer (score 4):

> A new abstract method: **public void display(Graphics g);** should be added to the base and derived classes

You haven't done this step correctly because I notice that you are calling `thearray[i].display();` when `display` is intended to have a parameter.

If you create the `display` method correctly, then you are handed the Graphics object that you can use, for example:

```
class Line extends Shape {
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;

    @Override
    public void display(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK so im still new to the website and cant really find a way to reply with new codes, so ill edit my post showing you one of the classes to see if I did it right because I think I tried this and I was getting an error saying it couldn't identify (Graphics g)

Comment: *"cannot identify ..."* You probably need to `import java.awt.Graphics;`.

Comment: its not cannot identify, its cannot find symbol

Comment: Wait I see. You need to do `thearray[i].display(g);`.

Comment: I put import java.awt.* and import javax.swing.* on top of each class that uses public void display(Graphics g) and then I put the public abstract void display(Graphics g) in my parent Shape class, and when I override it in each class and run it, it still gives me an empty Shape window

Comment: Tried the thearray[i].display(g); and still returns an empty window